# Styling a table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                    
        <td>Content</td>                                        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to style it something like this...

[image]

I tried it with CSS like this :

```
table td {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;
    border-right: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;
}
```

But can't get my expecting result. I can't use inline style with this issue.

Hope someone will help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Also tried adding this -  `tr:last-child {
border-bottom: none;
}` but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pjLFY/

You almost got it right.

You need to set the border to none of `td`'s in last `tr`, but you only set the border of that **row** to none.

```
table tr:last-child td {
     border-bottom: none; 
}

table td:last-child {
     border-right: none; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. `last-child` not working in IE 7 & 8. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, `:last-child` is supported by IE9+ only .

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it using `:last-child` so
try using this.

```
table td:last-child
{
    border-right:none;
}
table tr:last-child td
{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpdKn/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table td {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    width: 33%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;
    border-right: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;
    background: #FFFDDC;
}
table td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `:last-child`, and you know the background color of the page, try adding this:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding with `none` or `0`, you can use `:last-child` with `:not` like this:

```css
table td {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table tr:not(:last-child) td {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;  
}
table td:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px dashed #b4b4b4;    
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvSXe/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. `:not` is completely new to me.

Comment: @TNK Check out the documentation on `:not` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/:not).